# How to read aloud "->" or "::" sign in PHP OOP?

Tags: php, oop

We often use `$class_object->class_procedure` or `self::class_procedure` in PHP OOP. While reading aloud your code, how do you read out these conventions?

Comment: Curious, in what cases do you need to spell it? Cannot think of a case from my experience I ever needed that.

Comment: he wants to know how you would say it in conversation

Comment: @iedoc: and I asked in what cases you need to use it in conversation? I'd just say - you call object's method. That's enough to get what I mean

Comment: yeah, that's exactly how i answered, haha, but it looks like not everyone agrees

Comment: apparently people believe you should say "class object arrow class method" in conversation? I would probably laugh if i heard someone say it like that

Comment: "Tiny rocket".  Maybe that's =>, I can't remember.

Comment: @JohnBrodie `return ':)';`.

Comment: @JohnBrodie Tiny rocket!! ha ha ha.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`->` is the [object operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php). Typically called the *arrow* in conversation. If I were reading the code, I might say:

> class object *arrow* class method

`::` is the [static resolution operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php). I doesn't read as well in conversation. The docs say *double colon*. I might say:

> class *colon colon* static method

**Note:** Reading code aloud can be awkward regardless of how you name syntax. Furthermore, it will depend greatly on your audience. I am sharing what I've heard, seen used in books, or found in the docs.

Comment: Yeah, I think I will take this. This goes much in tune with .Net convention where we read "txtText.Text" as "txtText dot Text"... straight as it comes. How about self::proc though? Should I read out "self procedure proc"?

Comment: *"self double colon proc".*

Comment: I have never heard someone say "class object arrow class method" in conversation

Comment: Thanks. Now this will help me in long run... in seminars, presentations and group discussions etc. :-)

Comment: @iedoc: I actually may think of a use case for that: let's suppose you have a secretary in your office and you want her to fix something in your code straight on the production server. So you call her and start telling what to put to the file, while blocked by traffic jam.

Comment: ok, that's a good point zerkms

Comment: Just answering the question. Don't hate. At least I didn't break out the *spaceship*, `<=>`. :)

Answer (score 4):

You could use their [token names](http://php.net/manual/en/tokens.php):

- `->` (Object Operator AKA Arrow)
- `::` (Paamayim Nekudotayim OR Double Colon OR Static Object Operator)

Or just say:

> [static] method X of object Y

Comment: "Object operator" doesn't sound well though.

Comment: @zerkms: Sounds better than arrow operator IMO tho.

Comment: why not call `+` math operator then? "Object operator" doesn't express well what it does.

Comment: @zerkms: That would be the addition or plus operator. I don't follow the logic.

Comment: well, `+` is a `number operator` then. `->` is used with objects ---> then it's object operator. `+` is used with numbers ---> then it's number operator. "object operator" isn't expressive enough. Something like "object members access operator" would be better

Comment: + for a concise answer. However, I agree with @zerkms that you missed *arrow*.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary: I use arrow all the time, but I was aiming for something more formal. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

Class object's class procedure

Self's class procedure

Comment: "class object's class procedure" O_o --- "class object's" --- is redundant. Object always created as a class instance. "class procedure" -- there is no such term in php.

Comment: the class contains the procedure, so you use "'s" to represent possession. It's how i learned it in school, and how i've always said and heard it said

Comment: in php there are no procedures. There are functions and methods.

Comment: @zerkms: ...plus `::` doesn't necessarily represent a call to [it]self.

Answer (score 1):

For the static version (`self::class_procedure`), keep it simple.. "double colon"